# Removal of gas bubbles from an enclosed container

Tags: fluid-dynamics

How to remove the gas bubbles produced in a small enclosed container (one end of the container is  sealed with a membrane) during electrohydraulic discharge process, between two electrodes immersed in water? 
since I am  using an enclosed container, I cannot use vacuum method to remove gas bubbles.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix into the fluid a chemical which will react with the gas and consume the bubble. that chemical is called a "getter" and is commonly used in boiler systems to remove dissolved gases from solution before they have the opportunity to create bubbles. I do not know if the rest of your apparatus would be compatible with the getter chemistry.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Nielson. Can you tell me the examples of ''getter'' chemicals to remove the bubbles?

Comment: I cannot, but they are available as commercial products sold under the general classification of "feedwater conditioners"- used to prepare water for use in industrial power generation boilers and hot water heating systems.